# Arabic NER get multiple entity

Tags: python, nlp

I have an Arabic  NER algorithm in Python and it classified as  below list

[('للأمم', 'B-ORG'), ('المتحدة', 'I-ORG'), ('أنطونيو', 'B-PERS'), ('دونالد', 'I-PERS')]

How can I get a combination of B-ORG and I-ORG as ORGANIZATION ..
Also B-PERS and I-PERS as PERSON

please

Comment: What should be the desired output?

Comment: Thanks . It should be('أنطوني دونالد': 'PERSON','للأمم المتحدة': 'ORGANIZATION')

Comment: And which library do you use now?

Comment: I am using sklearn  library svm algorithm to classify text .